# How to get rid of spacing on edge of screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Everytime I start a new react project and I specify `width: 100%` for any item (let's just say a navbar) it stretches horizontally and then leaves like 5 px or so worth of "margin" or spacing between it and the edge. I'll attach a picture below.

It's kind of hard to see, but if you look closely right above the top border, you can see the bottom of the bookmark bar - that amount of spacing is on the left and right sides of the nav bar as well. Any ideas? (I've tried setting margin to 0, but didn't work)

[image: Here's the image]

Comment: Where did you apply the `margin: 0`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `body` adds a 8px margin.. use `body { margin: 0px; }` in your main CSS to fix this.
This is not a bug, just a default behaviour